# scale_size_identity() removes size legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I´m building a bubble plot in ggplot2 and need to create a legend with a scale.

My working data is the following

```
Var1    Var2    Var3
A   1   10
B   2   90
C   3   20
D   4   50
E   5   70
G   6   40
H   7   20
```

The code is the following:

```
  ggplot(t.df,aes(Var2,Var1,fill=Var1))+
  geom_point(aes(size=Var3/10),shape=21)+
  scale_size_identity()+
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_line(linetype=2,color="black",size=0.05,),
  axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0))
```

[image]

When I include scale_size_identity the size legends dissapears. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: try `scale_size_identity(guide="legend")`

Comment: I have tried that baptiste but it doesn´t works...

Comment: hmm, seems like a bug, you could try reporting it to the maintainers

Comment: baptiste's suggestion worked for me, including a `trans_new` contstruct from `scales`.

Answer (score 0):

First if you want two different variables legend is easy, just take out `scale_size_identity()` and it works:

```
ggplot(t.df,aes(Var2,Var1,fill=Var1))+
geom_point(aes(size=Var3/10),shape=21)+
theme(panel.grid.major=element_line(linetype=2,color="black",size=0.05,),
    axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0))
```

[image]

If that is not what you want let me know to help

Comment: Thanks Derek. But if I remove scale_size_identity the scale isn´t the same and the differences between points aren´t so obvious. For example if you compare the two graphs you will se that the last pink point it the second graph is bigger than in the first.. Is there any way of doing this without removing scale_size_identity()?

Comment: I will Try @FranciscoC